Set 2fa password and add recovery email on telegram account via telethon
I looked in documentation and see this client method:
client.edit_2fa(new_password=new_password,
                email="my_test_email@example.com",
                email_code_callback=get_code_manually()
)

But the question is, What is the "email_code_callback"? Documentation says that "The length of the
code will be passed to the callback as an input parameter." and I struggle to understand what I need to do with this length.
I wrote function, that scraped code from email, but it didn't work (because I didn't receive any letters from telegram). A simple function like that, passed as email_code_callback, didn't work (the letter wasn't received either):
def get_code_manually():
    code = input('Get code from letter')
    if not code:
        code = None
    return code

